# How do I get permission to send an email using MailApp.sendEmail from my google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Here is my script code

```
function SendEmail(emailAddress) {                                                                      
                 var message = 'This is your response';                                                   
                var subject = 'You have feed back in the parking lot';      
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

and in my Google sheet the command for running the script is `=IF(ISTEXT(F2),SendEmail(B2))`.

Basically if **F2** was empty but now contains text then it should run the script **SendEmail** passing the email address in spot **B2** to the function.

However when I try this in google sheets it tells me #error

> Exception: You do not have permission to call MailApp.sendEmail. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail (line 8)..

I understand that the `MailApp.sendEmail` has the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail` , but How do I authorize my google sheet to run that function?